# AWS Cloudformation fails when I provide a QueueName

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

There is this behaviour I have observed sometimes with Cloudformation in AWS.

```
Description: Something here....
Parameters:
  StackName:
    Description: reference the StackName
    Type: String

  StageName:
    Description: reference the environment type (local, alpha, beta, uat, prod)
    Type: String

Resources:
  FileGenerationDLQ:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${StackName}-FileGenerationDLQ-${StageName}"
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 20
      VisibilityTimeout: 925

  FileGenerationQueue:
    DependsOn: FileGenerationDLQ
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: !Sub "${StackName}-FileGeneration-${StageName}"
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 1209600
      ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: 925
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt FileGenerationDLQ.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 1
```

The above fails. However, if I comment the QueueName it works.

Ofcourse I have other things in the template but I have omitted them for privacy.
Could anyone point me to the doc why this is happening? Does this have something to do with the Cloudformation template versions?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Could not create FileGenerationDLQ . Very vague error

Comment: Embedded stack XXXX was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [FileGenerationDLQ].

Comment: What are the actual values of your `StackName` and `StageName`?